# Filtering or determining warehouse deals via Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-product-advertising-api

I have a project I'm working on that involves working with warehouse deals on Amazon. I've been looking and trying to find a way to pull *only* warehouse deals using the Product Advertising API. So, question #1 is, is there a way of achieving this?

If there is not a way, then question #2 is, if I pull a list of items, is there a way of determining whether any one of those items is a warehouse deal or not?

Essentially, I need a way to find warehouse deals using the API. Does anyone have any ideas I could try out?

Comment: Hey Ethan, did you ever solve this? I'm working on something similar. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulDessert, well, I'm a bit late, aren't I? I should check back here on SO more, and try to be more active these days.

This project is hard to recall at this point, as it was so little and not at all long-lasting.

I'm not sure what I can do to help and I don't have that code on the computer I'm using now, but if we were able to get in touch personally, I'd be happy to share what I do have.

Comment: Hey Ethan! No worries. I was able to figure it out. There is a way, it's just very dirty. There is no direct way to do it. I had to run 2 API calls and process the data in order to get the results I wanted. I spent a bunch of time on it, then Amazon denied my affiliate application. So, now I'm left with a dead project ;). Check it out if you're interested. www.jungleflip.com

Comment: Hello, I find my self needing help with this years after it's posted!  Would one of you be willing to connect? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some regions Warehouse Deals are simply BrowseNodes. This is the case in DE. In UK and US it seems to be different. If your region works like DE:

1: You could include the Warehouse Deal BrowseNode in your search request. This does not work with searches in the All and Blended search indexes.

2: You can use the BrowseNodes response group in your search or ItemLookup calls to find out what BrowseNode an item belongs to. This gives you the whole ancestry of the BrowseNode. You just have to follow it up and check it against a known Warehouse Deals BrowseNodeId.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01/DG/RG_BrowseNodes.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel, while your answer is a good one, it just didn't apply to me. All the same, you get my vote, for providing a well-informed and accurate answer.

Comment: Well, damn, Daniel -- Your answer was, of course, *the* answer. I like AWS, but I think I'm going to stay away from Amazon's  front-facing (products and all that) APIs as much as a I can ;)

It was a year and a half ago, and my reply is so ill-informed. Your answer is, I think, correct. I never did find a "good" way around this issue.

Sorry that it took me this long to accept your answer.